# What is Sustainable philosophy of the Objective kind?

Tags: knowledge

Umm... new to site & so new Q.

Had to set up a new space to ask such a Question on Quora recently.
Called the Environment of Philosophy Space where there Q. & Answers
in reality explaining the bad shape of current & past taught philosophy.
Each one of us has had little responsibility for that nevertheless we
can and should have some knowledgeable responsibility to understand
a better need now for such an environment.
An ENVIRONMENT OF (better) SUSTAINABLE relevant knowledge...
or objective philosophy knowledge & it's wide-ranging learned BEHAVIOUR, that may be otherwise called "Critically rational knowledge".

P.s. talk of "truth" is and should be off-loaded when discussing Sustainable philosophy knowledge. Why? Because under the banner of "knowledge" or even "NEW knowledge" most if not all of the countless silly wranglings that occur in discussions here and at other sites are not needed if we need to learn some type of SUSTAINABLE behaviour knowledge. And this is an avoidance preference which can bring more benefit to subsequent discussions, discussions which we all have-to-have but should not hamper the getaway to some new environment of learning so to speak.. which we can all participate in, appreciate of and of course understand (with some help from interested others!).

What is Sustainable philosophy of the Objective kind ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Sustainable philosophy"? The philosophy (if any) supporting [Sustainability](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/sustainability/v-1)?

Comment: By "sustainable", do you mean perhaps *practical* or *applied*? Or is it the quality, clarity, or novelty that concerns you?

Comment: what is meant IS Both PRACTICAL AND APPLIED. Sustainable philosophy aims AT IT'S OWN "New knowledge environment" where most SUSTAINABLE problems have their objective discussions. Including solutions.

Comment: It may help to include one or more examples -- preferably real-world -- of sustainable versus unsustainable. This would be better in the question itself than in the comments. When speaking of a problem or social issue not widely discussed, providing examples can help others to understand its scope and significance. Naturally one might choose well-known examples, so that others can more easily relate.

Comment: Please see the other answer by Michael about "Sustainable philosophy". Describing sustainability as a philosophy clarifying it cannot be correct. It's the other way around, where sustainability DESCRIBES and so LIMITS A philosophy. As you may know "philosophy" like ANY OTHER SUBJECT HAS ITS DESCRIBABLE & real limits. Even current subjective, hi-faluting rote philosophy. Because it is, always will be, where students right now have to learn about so called "greats" where these greats were the only ones around who COULD READ & WRITE.

Comment: Enough of this for now. I am new to this site but lets not critically end the philosophy egg before it hatches so to speak. Practise can make perfect in this respect. Do any of u know if & where there may exist a place or site for my major a university... in the History of Ideas. Perhaps then there would be a better environment for sustainable philosophy and it's fledging environment.